# How to Get value from an inherited class, and from a variable at the same time

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

How to **Get value** from an **inherited** class, and **from a variable** at the same time?

This is an illustrative example that explains the problem :

```
Public Class Table

    'IF Chooce Shared Work In Inherits Only
    'IF Not Chooce Shared Work In Variant Only
    Public Shared RecordCount As Integer

End Class

Public Class Customer 
    Inherits Table

    Private Sub GetRecordCount_From_Inherits()

        MsgBox(RecordCount) ' Here View (RecordCount)

    End Sub

    Sub GetRecordCount_From_Variant()


        Dim x As New Table
        MsgBox(x.RecordCount) 'Here Not View (RecordCount)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I mean, they do not show the property

Comment: Customer dopes not need to create a `New Table` it *is* a Table type since it inherits from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with such a code:

```
       Table.RecordCount = 5
        Customer.RecordCount = 4
        Dim t1 As New Table()
        t1.print()
        Dim c1 As New Customer()
        c1.print()
```

Then I tried commenting one of those two lines:

```
        Table.RecordCount = 5
        Customer.RecordCount = 4
```

Only thing that is logical right now is that there is only one variable.

> VB doesn't have static, it has shared

Inheritance of static members works differently. You will have to redesign this class.